# Running a function before willInsertElement in an Ember View

Tags: ember.js

I want to set some variables before a view is rendered. Specifically, I want to create semi-random class names and ids:

```
buttonBarId: ""
inputClass: ""

random: 0

willInsertElement: ->
  @set('random', Math.floor(Math.random() * (999999 - 100000 + 1)) + 100000)
  @set('buttonBarId', 'wmd-button-bar-' + @get('random'))
  @set('inputClass', 'wmd-input-' + @get('random'))
```

I was hoping that that `willInsertElement` would do the trick, but unfortunately by the time it's called, the view has already been created (it just hasn't been placed in the DOM yet). Is there a way I could set these variables before view is created?

Comment: This should still work. How are you syncing those values to the DOM?

Comment: With `classBinding=inputClass`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run it before (or actually when) the view is **created**, rather than **rendered**, you should override the "init" method of this view.
It will be called when the view is instantiated from the view class.
Oh, and **don't** forget to run this._super() somewhere in this init method. Otherwise nothing will work.